# [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I'm creating Laravel project this problem arise. How can I solve it? Please help me.

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2014%2484e1e32f72dce61514995dc877a6f982ca02c9bef07deeccc180e9c3bc6c0344.json"
>   file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.   1 404 Not Found)
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
>   [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

Comment: Any One is their

Comment: try deleting composer.lock and running composer install again;.